# Prove that number of divisors of any nonzero number is finitive

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that number of divisors of any nonzero number is finitive.

I know the formula that using that we can show that they are finitive.
But we had this question befor learning this and we cannot use it I tried to dividing it to an other number and prove the theorm using induction But I can't.Any ideas?

Comment: If $a \mid b$, and $b \neq 0$, what can you say about the relation between $\lvert a\rvert$ and $\lvert b\rvert$?

Comment: Trivially the number of (positive) divisor of $n$ is $\le n$, because a divisor cannot be $>n$

Comment: @DanielFischer  $\mid b \mid\ge \mid a \mid$ But what to do with this?

Comment: How many integers with $\lvert k \rvert \leqslant \lvert n\rvert$ are there for a nonzero integer $n$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Well why don't you post an answer.Your comment is a full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the multiplicativity of the modulus it follows that for $n \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}$ we have $k \mid n \implies \lvert k\rvert \leqslant \lvert n\rvert$. Since $\{ k \in \mathbb{Z} : \lvert k\rvert \leqslant \lvert n\rvert\}$ has only finitely many elements (namely $2\lvert n\rvert + 1$), it follows that $n\in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}$ has only finitely many divisors. (Of course the bound on the number of divisors obtained from this argument is abysmal.)

Answer (score 1):

You can prove it by induction.

Clearly $1$ has only 1 divisor: namely, $1$ itself.

Next, fix a positive integer $n>1$ and suppose that all numbers less than $n$ have only finitely many divisors. Let $p$ be any prime dividing $n$. Then, $1\leq\frac{n}{p}<n$. Hence, by our inductive assumption, $\frac{n}{p}$ has only finitely many divisors. Since $p$ is prime, its only divisors are $1$ and $p$. Thus, $n=p\cdot\frac{n}{p}$ has only finitely many divisors.